# Java Read Each Line Into Separate Array

Tags: java, arrays, io

I have 1,000 lines of data in a text file and I would like each line to be its own float [].

```
1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3
```

Would result in:

```
 float[0] = {1,1,1,1,1,1}
 float[1] = {2,2,2,2,2,2}
 float[2] = {3,3,3,3,3,3}
```

Is this possible?  I could only find examples of loading an entire file into an array.  I tried hardcoding all the arrays, but exceeded the byte character limit of ~65,000

Comment: Is each line the same number of floats?

Comment: Yes, each line has the same number of floats.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
// this list will store all the created arrays
List<float[]> arrays = new ArrayList<float[]>();

// use a BufferedReader to get the handy readLine() function
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));

// this reads in all the lines. If you only want the first thousand, just
// replace these loop conditions with a regular counter variable
for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
    String[] floatStrings = line.split(",");
    float[] floats = new float[floatStrings.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < floats.length; ++i) {
        floats[i] = Float.parseFloat(floatStrings[i]);
    }
    arrays.add(floats);
}
```

Note that I haven't added any exception handling (readLine(), for example, throws IOException).

Answer (score 0):

- use a [LineIterator](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/LineIterator.html) to read each line without loading the whole file
- for each line, use a regular expression to extract figures like *(\d\.)+* and iterator over the matches found with methods like *find()* and *group()*

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>
<pre>

import java.io.FileReader;

public class Check {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        readingfile();
    }
    public static void readingfile() {
        try {
            FileReader read = new FileReader("D:\\JavaWkspace\\numbers.txt");
            int index;
            String nums1 = "";

            while ((index = read.read()) != -1) {
                if (((char) index) != '\n') {
                    nums1 += String.valueOf((char) index);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Problem statement: Print out the greatest number on each line:\n" + nums1);

            String f = nums1.substring(0, 14);
            String s = nums1.substring(15, 29);
            String t = nums1.substring(30);

            String[] fs = f.split(",");
            int size = fs.length;
            int[] arr = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(fs[i]);
            }
            int max = arr[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (max < arr[i]) {
                    max = arr[i];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\nGreatest number in the first line is:" + (max));

            String[] sstr = s.split(",");
            int size2 = sstr.length;
            int[] arr2 = new int[size2];
            for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
                arr2[i] = Integer.parseInt(sstr[i]);
            }

            int max2 = arr2[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
                if (max2 < arr2[i]) {
                    max2 = arr2[i];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\nGreatest number in the second line is:" + (max2));

            String[] str3 = t.split(",");
            int size3 = str3.length;
            int[] arr3 = new int[size3];
            for (int i = 0; i < size3; i++) {
                arr3[i] = Integer.parseInt(str3[i]);
            }

            int max3 = arr3[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++) {
                if (max3 < arr3[i]) {
                    max3 = arr3[i];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\nGreatest number in the third line is:" + (max3));
            read.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
</pre>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Loop over the line-delimited contents of the file with .split("\n") and then cast each result as float array. Here's how to convert the string into a float for you => http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00013.shtml

Comment: -1, this isn't an answer at all. You need some detail. Any detail.

Comment: That is literally what I just said.