# Java Read Each Line Into Separate ArrayList (String)

Tags: java, arraylist

Is it posible to put eachline (from txt file) to sepperate arraylist etc and put them incide Array DATABASE

I have a file with info of students something like that

Name Lastname yearsOld address
BEN DDD 12 14Drive
Olga Benar 12 23Ave

So in result I would have an ArrayLIST with arraylist(of each student)?

Comment: What do you want to occupy the arraylist of students, strings with their information?

Comment: I have a txt file with each line has student info Later on I need to search them using contains method (so I was going to put each student int o seperat arrayList and into one ArrayList where all students are)

Comment: I'm looking for same thing but in STRING http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523497/java-read-each-line-into-separate-array

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a model of your data?
E.g:

```
class Student {
    String name;
    String lastname;
    int yearsOld;
    ...more fields...
}
```

And use that to load your data into an `ArrayList<Student>`.

**EDIT:**
However, to answer your question. Use the IO library to read the file line by line:

```
public List<List<String>> processFile(String file) throws IOException {      
    List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       data.add(processLine(line));
    }
    br.close();
    return data;
}

public List<String> processLine(String line) {
    return Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")); //  Be aware of spaces in names, addresses etc.
}
```

Comment: but how do I put each line into seperate arraylist?

Comment: I belive there is suntax error somewhere... cant work

Comment: This is object oriented programming.  Store in your arraylist objects of type Student as suggested. Then you can iterate over the arraylist and discover the details as required.